# trying to Add and remove .class to an #id after a specific pixels scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

i have a div which i want to show user after they scroll 800px (basically that fixed div is overlapping header and footer when scrolled ) so i want to make that div visible only after scrolling 800px (which will pass the head banner) and stop div before #footer ection (unable to figure out how to stop that fixed div before footer).

it would be really great if can anyone tell how to make it visible only after 800px scroll.

```html
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $heightScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $defaultHeight = 800;

    if ( $heightScrolled < $defaultHeight )
    {
        $('#elements-main').removeClass("b")
    $('#elements-main').addClass("a")
        }
    else {
        $('#elements-main').addClass("b")
        }

});
```

Comment: Your else logic is not removing class `a` as the inverse of the if

Comment: @Taplar actually it's as whole isn't working it's not even adding classes to that div

Comment: Then please edit your question and make an [mcve].  It's very difficulty to debug code on it's own.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup will show the fixed div when not over header and footer region of the page. I hope this helps.

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    const scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    const offset = 800;
    const footerOffset = $('footer').offset();
    const $fixedCard = $('#main');
    const fixedCardHeight = $fixedCard.outerHeight();
    
    if (scrollPosition > offset && scrollPosition < (footerOffset.top - fixedCardHeight)) {
      $fixedCard.attr('class', 'fixed-visible');
    } else {
      $fixedCard.attr('class', 'fixed-hidden');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
 height: 3000px;
 display: flex;
 margin: 0;
 align-items: stretch;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-direction: column;
}
header, footer {
 height: 800px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
#main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #23e4c1;
}
.fixed-hidden {
 display: none;
}

.fixed-visible {
 display: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<header>Header Area</header>
<main>
<div id="main" class="fixed-hidden">Fixed Div</div>
</main>
<footer>Footer Area</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you much it'working but without footer partif i keep that footer condition it stay hidden

Comment: i am glad it was helpful :)

Comment: i'm glad hat you help as i tried almost 12 8 to 9 snippets nothing worked out